# How to express “I wonder what it’s named after”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

I was thinking along the lines of “je me demande ce qu’il est nommé d’après,” but it seems wrong. What would be better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could say :

> Je me demande de quoi il/elle/cela tire son nom.
>
> Je me demande d'où il/elle/cela tire son nom.
>
> Je me demande d'où vient son nom.

Comment: Également : de quoi il porte le nom ; d'où il reçoit / a reçu son nom ; comme quoi il s'appelle.

Comment: *Porter le nom de* is more restricted than *to be named after*. It implies that the exact same name has been given. You can say *Le polonium tire son nom du pays natal de Marie Curie, mais il ne porte pas le nom de ce pays*. Because polonium and Pologne are two different words.

Comment: Cela a du sens. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

I think we can utilise either porter or nommer.

Porter:

> Je me demande de quoi il porte le nom.

Nommer:

> Je me demande de quoi il est nommé.

I guess we may use se nommer as well. But I am not sure:-)!

> Je me demande de quoi il se nomme.

Comment: Could you say "Je me demande d'après quoi il est nommé"?

Comment: No natif here:-)! I think so.

Comment: *Se nommer* or *être nommé* is not used with *de* + something. You would use it eg in *il se nomme Albert*, but not to express that the name comes from something (or then possibly with *en référence à* or *d'après *). *Porter le nom* is rather used to refer to given names such as a family name or the name of a city, country, etc., and means the name is exactly the same (eg *elle porte le nom de sa mère*), so the usage is more restricted.

Comment: I asked this question after seeing it in [this wiki article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mont%C3%A9e_Saint-Clair-Duport), where it says *Nommée d'après le nom d'usage de Clair-Dominique-Eugène Duport...* Are you saying that's an incorrect sentence?

Comment: *Nommer d'après* is not incorrect, maybe awkward at worst, and "non-native" in *d'après quoi est-il nommé ?*. *Nommer de* would in any case not be correct.

Comment: d'après = according to

Comment: *D'après* can mean "according to" but also "taking x as model" (eg *un film de Spielberg, d'après un roman de Stephen King*). This is the meaning with *nommer*. A tricky example: "d'après mon professeur, la capitale des USA a été nommée d'après le premier président ". It is far-fetched and may sound ambiguous to non-native speakers but it is correct.

Comment: @Greg C'est tout nouveau pour moi. Merci encore une fois !